# c++ Derived class object has no member, why?

Tags: c++

I have this problem in my homework.

I have this 2 classes:

-an user class:

```
   class user
{
protected:
int id;
std::string password;
std::string name;
bool online;
static int usersCounter;
static int onlineCounter;

public:
user(std::string = "user", std::string = "1234");

bool connect(std::string);
void disconnect();
void changePassword(std::string);
void changeName(std::string);
virtual void printInfo();

static int getOnlineNo() 
{
    return onlineCounter;
}

static int getTotalUsers() 
{
    return usersCounter;
}

friend class admin;
};
```

and an admin class:

```
class admin : public user
{
public:
admin(std::string name = "admin", std::string password = "admin"):
    user(name, password){}

void disconnectUser(user&);
void viewUsers( user** );
void printInfo() override;
};
```

When I try to make a polymorphic object and call a function from admin (a function specific for admin, as disconnectUser(...) or viewUsers(...)) I get errors as "class "user" has no member "viewUsers".

```
user* usr = new admin();
usr->viewUsers(&usr);//error
```

Is this something usual and I did a wrong design or It should work and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `usr` actually points to an instance of `admin` and not `user`. The whole point of "polymorphic object" is that the caller doesn't need to know what class the pointer really points to, and can work entirely in terms of base interface.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment if you define a class of type `A` you can access only public methods and property of that class.

In your case, `viewUsers` is present only in the `admin` class while you're using the generic `user` class.

You must use inheritance very careful because is very easy to put the wrong methods inside classes or make a wrong inheritance. For example, are you sure the method `viewUsers` must be inside the `admin` class? Usually, if a function doesn't depend on the class is best put it outside the class.

Comment: The opening sentence can be read as the opposite of what I think you are trying to say. That or it's wrong. Either way, I recommend rewording it so that it is clearly correct.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I understand now.